# Cant Target and Apply New CSS Rule to a Div

Tags: jquery, css

I encountered big difficulties updating bg color on part of my site.
What I am trying to do is to simply change the `.container` div with id `#footer`,
but all of the rules which I have written are not working!

```
#footer.container{ background-color:#4C555A !important; }
```

or

```
#footer{ background-color:#4C555A !important; }
```

I even tried to do this through jQuery like

```
$( "#footer.container" ).css("background-color","yellow");
$( "#footer" ).css("background-color","yellow");
```

but none of them worked!

Can you please take a look at [This Link](http://www.behfuruz.com/#footer) and let me know what I am missing or doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong, the bgcolor is #4C555A;

Comment: there is not `.container` div with `#logo`

Comment: It not clear whether you want to apply changes on div with id #logo or #footer. If you want to apply css on logo then you have to replace # footer.container with #logo.container

Comment: Sorry , my bad it is footer not logo

Comment: this css is applied `#footer.container{ background-color:#4C555A !important; }` which is on line no 23 of `style.css`

Comment: I want to change the sides color! container color!

Comment: i think you are talking about body color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the ".footer-new" div:

```
.footer-new {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #4C555A !important;
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$( "#footer.container" ).css("background-color","#4C555A");
```

Is that what you need?